# How does IIS "know" which website uses which PHP version?

Tags: php, iis

I have 2 websites on the same application pool with IIS 10.
One of them is a PHP app using PHP 7.3, and the second app is the updated version of the same app using PHP 8.1.

Now I just copied the newer app to the `C:/inetpub` folder, and then added the PHP 8.1 FastCGI module (`.exe`) via the Handler Mappings.

So now the Handler Mappings show 2 FastCGI modules: One with the path to PHP 8.1 folder, and one with path to the PHP 7.3 folder.

When I use `phpinfo()` on each app, it shows that each app uses the correct PHP version - the old app uses PHP 7.3, and the new uses PHP 8.1

I restarted the websites and it still worked after showing the same information.

But where does this happen on IIS? Where do I match the module to a specific site? This is important because they are not backwards compatible, and before I added the path to PHP 8.1 in Handler Mappings, I got an error on the new website that it requires PHP >8.1.

But once I added the PHP 8.1 Fast CGI module it automatically detected it, and automatically assigned it to the new website. But how? And what if I want to map it specifically to a website and not let it detect it automatically? And why didn't it try to assign the PHP 8.1 FastCGI module to the old app?

**Update:** I think I was wrong: Each website has its own Handler Mappings, just in my case it first "copied" some default Mappings, and I just added the PHP 8.1 to it only. So looks like there are some "global" Handler Mappings settings that are assigned when you create a new website, and then you can modify specifically for that website, which is what I did. I just got confused because I saw it's the same as the Handler Mappings I chose on the entire server window.

so I believe that at first, global Handler Mappings were set to the PHP 7.3 app (because I only had one app so didn't really checked which handle mappings I edit) and when I added a new website it just used them. (But when I deleted the mapping for PHP 7.3 specifically for the new app, it did not remove that from the 7.3 app)

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/run-multiple-versions-of-php-on-iis